# How to add Azure custom Policy for Azure Data Factory to only use Azure Key Vault during the Linked Service Creation?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-data-factory, azure-policy

How to add Azure custom Policy for Azure Data Factory to only use Azure Key Vault during the Linked Service Creation for fetching the Data Store Credentials instead of credentials being put up directly in ADF Linked Service. Please suggest ARM or PowerShell methods for the policy implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of yesterday, the Data Factory Azure Policy integration is available which means you can now find some built-in policies that can be assigned to ADF.

One of those is exactly what you're asking for as you can see in the image below. You can find more information [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-data-factory/data-factory-azure-policy-integration-is-live-now/ba-p/2120160)

[image]

Edit: Based on your comment, I'm editing this answer with the info you want. When it comes to custom policies, it's pretty much up to you to come up with them and create what fits your needs. In your particular case, I've created one policy that does what you want, please see [here](https://github.com/pfiadeiro/azure-content/tree/master/azure-policies/DataFactory/audit-integration-runtimes).

This policy will audit your data factory linked services and check if they're using a self-hosted integration runtime. Currently, that check is only done for a few types of integration runtimes (if you look at the policy, you can see 5 of them) which means that if you want to check more types of linked services, you'll need to add them to the list of allowed values and select them when assigning the policy definition.

Bear in mind that for some linked services types, such as Key Vault, that check won't make sense since that service can't use a self-hosted IR

Comment: Thank you Pedro. Yes this is what I'm looking for. In general, how can I add a custom policy at ADF Linked Service level. e.g. I want to enforce use of Self-Hosted IR in Linked Service, how to create this custom policy script or similar any other policy script. As there will be limited built-in policies available from Microsoft, what are the custom policy options available to enforce policies at ADF component level?

Comment: Hi Yogesh, just edited my answer based on your comment

Comment: This is perfect. I will try it. Thanks a lot Pedro!

Comment: Great, hope this gives you what you need. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct so it ca help other people if this solves your issue.